# Como inserir CSS externo no Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

Gostaria de saber como inserir um arquivo externo de css dentro de uma view do Codeigniter 3.
Configurei o **$autoload['helper'] = array('url');**
tentei fazer a chamada das seguintes formas:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=site_url('application/views/css/main.css')?>">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=site_url('css/main.css')?>">
```

Testei também utilizando o **base_url();** porém os resultados foram os mesmo.
Ele imprime o html com o caminho correto mas não está aplicando os estilos. Se eu clicar nesse link dentro do visualizador de código fonte do navegador ele me redireciona para o 404 padrão do codeigniter.

Comment: Como está a estrutura de pastas do seu apache? localhost aponta para seu projeto ou precisa entrar em mais um nível de diretórios?

Comment: Mostre como esta sua estrutura de pastas

Comment: O problema estava no meu htaccess.
estava falando incluir o diretório na regra.
Antes: RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|/css|js|images|robots.txt)
Depois:RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|includes/css|includes/js|includes/images|robots.txt)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT

Certifique- se de chamar o método de ajuda no Controller ou o URL helper.

`$this->load->helper('url');`

ORIGINAL

Use a **base_url()** mesmo. Mas aí você tem que configurar a URL para retornar o caminho da pasta raiz do seu site.

Supondo uma estrutura assim:

- www.raiz.com

  - index.php
  - css

    - meucss.css

E que você queira incluir o CSS no arquivo index.php, então, o base_url seria `$config['base_url'] = "http://www.raiz.com/"`.

Em index.php, você chamaria o CSS:

`<link href="<? echo base_url();?>/css/meucss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Comment: Quando você diz:
"E que você queira incluir o CSS no arquivo index.php, então, o base_url seria $config['base_url'] "
Você quer dizer na view? ou no controller?

Comment: Refiro-me ao arquivo de configuração do CodeIgniter em `application/config/config.php`

Comment: configurei da seguinte forma:
No config.php $config['base_url'] = 'localhost/CodeIgniter-3.0.3/';
Na view: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/main.css">
O resultado no html gerado foi:
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="localhost/CodeIgniter-3.0.3/css/main.css">
Porém ele continua com o mesmo problema de não inserir e se eu tentar clicar no link da visualização do fonte no navegador, o mesmo me leva para a página de erro do codeigniter.

Comment: @JahnKrauss tente `http://localhost/CodeIgniter-3.0.3/`. Só para entender, por que não usar a url relativa mesmo?

Comment: mesmo com a url relativa ele não acessa!

Comment: Você adicionou o método de ajuda no Controller? `$this->load->helper('url');`

Comment: Descobri o problema, houve uma alteração no codeigniter no patch 3.0.3, vou coletar mais informações e postar aqui para futuras dúvidas. A princípio agora deve ser usado de uma outra forma, foi feito para evitar Host header injections.

Comment: Simplificando a chamada do CSS de acordo com a resposta, pode-se usar `<?=` e `?>` no lugar de `<? echo` e `;?>` e usar o diretório dentro da função `base_url()`.

Exemplo:
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=base_url('css/meucss.css')?>">`