# Como carregar CSS externo pelo CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter

Preciso chamar esta folha de estilo externa, porém ela não carrega de jeito nenhum, vi uma pergunta semelhante aqui, porém não notei uma resposta conclusiva, uma vez que estou usando o CodeIgniter 3 adiante.

O erro que aparece é este:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Como poderia resolver este problema?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>RR Telecon</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/assets/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/assets/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="reader">
        teste
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O link é este, mais não me resolveu não http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102191/como-inserir-css-externo-no-codeigniter-3

Comment: Abra o `Inspector de elemento` do seu navegador, vá até em `Console` e atualize a página, veja se aparece algum erro. Se aparecer, poste aqui para tentarmos lhe ajudar.

Comment: Alisson Acioli atualizei o erro que aparece, está no rodapé da pergunta

Comment: Por acaso é só o home.css que não esta carregando ou são todos?

Comment: Todos, não se carrega, é alguma regra na nova versão do codeigniter eu acho, e pelo que eu tenho lido também, mais ainda não consegui resolver.

Comment: tente assim `<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap-theme.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`

Answer (score 1):

Erro 404 significa que ele não está achando o arquivo no local indicado. No console do navegador, em qual linha está dando o erro? pelo oque vi aí, está faltando uma barra (/) depois do base_url quando você chama o home.php. Pode ser esse o seu problema. substitua pelo código abaixo e teste.

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/assets/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/assets/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/assets/css/home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Mas teria que ver se no seu base_url está com a barra (/) no final. caso tenha, será necessário remover todas as barras quando você coloca o link. Ficando dessa forma:

```
    <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Teste das duas formas e veja oque acontece :)

Answer (score 0):

Use o diretório dentro da função `base_url()`, e para encurtar um pouco mais a chamada, utilize `<?=` e `?>` no lugar de `<?php echo` e `; ?>`.

Exemplo:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=base_url('assets/css/bootstrap-theme.css')?>">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=base_url('assets/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css')?>">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.css')?>">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')?>">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=base_url('assets/css/home.css')?>">
```

Veja como o código ficou mais limpo e agradável de se ler.